# codeigniter : insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert posted data to database as below.

```
public function submit_signup(){
            if($this->input->post('submit')){
                $user_data['data']=array(
                    'username'   =>     $this->input->post('username'),
                    'email'      =>     $this->input->post('email'),
                    'password'   =>     $this->input->post('password'),
                    'mobile'     =>     $this->input->post('mobile') 
                );
            }
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            if($this->user_model->register_user($user_data)){
                echo 'data entered';
            }
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('test',$user_data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

My Model:

```
class user_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function register_user($data){
        if(!$this->db->insert('user',$data)) {
            echo 'Data not entered';
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

When I press form this is what I get

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Need your help

Answer (score 0):

Make your array as

```
 $user_data=array(
                    'username'   =>     $this->input->post('username'),
                    'email'      =>     $this->input->post('email'),
                    'password'   =>     $this->input->post('password'),
                    'mobile'     =>     $this->input->post('mobile') 
                );
```

Remove `['data']` part.Then use it into insert query

Check [**manuall**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html?highlight=insert#query-builder-insert)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass your exact array **$user_data['data']** into the model function

```
if($this->user_model->register_user($user_data['data']))
{
    echo 'data entered';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert data to database you can try this :

```
$this->load->model('user_model');

$user_data=[
  'username'   =>     $this->input->post('username'),
  'email'      =>     $this->input->post('email'),
  'password'   =>     $this->input->post('password'),
  'mobile'     =>     $this->input->post('mobile') 
];
$this->user_model->register_user($user_data)
```

or

//without model

```
$this->db->insert('table_name', $user_data);
```